# Amazon Kinesis 1 MB size limit workaround

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

As reported in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html)

> The maximum size of the data payload of a record before base64-encoding is up to 1 MiB.

Since that I need to process records that may have the size larger than 1 MB this limit may be an issue.

Is there any workaround to overcome this limit? And in case any proven solution already implemented and used by anyone? (I'd like avoiding "reinventing the wheel")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two choices: break the payload into multiple records or save it outside the stream, for example in S3.

For the first option, you can utilize `PartitionKey` and `SequenceNumberForOrdering` ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html#API_PutRecord_RequestParameters)). Assign a unique partition key (such as a UUID) to each source record. If you need to break the source into sub-1MB chunks, you set the sequence number for chunks 2..N to the returned sequence number of the previous chunk.

This will then require the clients to examine the partition key for retrieved records, and reconstruct the original record if necessary. Note that they may need to buffer several chunks (for different source records).

Externalizing the data will simplify both the producer and consumer code. Again, create a unique identifier for each source record, but rather than writing the record to the stream write it to S3 with that identifier as its key. Then write the key to the stream. The consumer will then retrieve the actual data from S3 when it reads the ID from the stream.

This second approach does require more management: you will need to add a lifecycle rule to S3 to delete the records, and you'll need to ensure that this life-cycle rule lets the objects live *at least* as long as the stream's retention period (I would probably set an 8 day TTL regardless of stream retention period, because S3 is cheap).

If you only have infrequent large records, and especially if you have lots of small records, then writing everything to S3 will be inefficient. In that case you can adopt a hybrid model, in which you write a data structure to the stream that either contains the actual data or a reference to external storage.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I may be interested in the approach of splitting the payload and merge it afterwards. But I would not like to "reinvent the wheel" and rewrite the logic for this task if it was already implemented by someone else. For example I found this project https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-aggregation/tree/master/python by AWS Labs: can someone who used it confirm that it may fit this use case or probably recommend a different library?

Comment: Hi @Vzzarr Can you confirm if the module for aggregation and deaggregation(https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-aggregation/tree/master/python) suited your needs? From its ReadMe, it does aggregation at the producer end and deaggregation at consumer end, while ur requirement was reverse of it.

Comment: HI @ShuchiSethi at the end has been used pure Kafka to dump data in S3 and then AWS Glue (an ETL service from AWS) to implement our architecture. The library didn't seem to fit my requirements so I moved to a "quite different" solution ahah

Comment: The linked project doesn't address this problem. It's an implementation of aggregation that fits multiple small Kinesis User records into a single Kinesis Data Stream record whose limit is 1MB to reduce costs and be bandwidth-efficient.

https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-aggregation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-kpl-concepts.html

Comment: Are this two alternatives of comparable speed ? Is S3 slower than "breaking the payload"  approach ?